# How to detect whether script was loaded client side or server side in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

How do I detect whether a script was loaded from `+page.server.js` or `+page.svelte`?

Is there a (Svelte) function that I can import to see the difference?

Comment: Do you truly need to differentiate between those or do you want to tell if it's running client or server side?  `+page.svelte` can run in either place.  I'm unaware of something built-in that can do what you asked.

Comment: @possum it seems sometimes `+page.svelte` has `window` defined and sometimes it doesn't. I need to know when I can call server functions and when not.

Comment: Then your question in the body is not the one you wanted to ask.  If you need to know you're running on the server you can just test if `window` is defined to tell.  `import.meta.env.SSR` should also provide the same information.

Comment: @possum I figured I needed to add my code to `onMount()` in order to have `window` defined and thus know the code is running client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`browser` flag](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser) you can check:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
```